# Tkinter Cancel button that stops the whole script

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

So, basically I am playing with Tkinter and automatization of web page in Python and the thing that I want to add is the window pop up that allows me to select one of two options (today vs tomorrow in my case).
This is the code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
def center_window(w=300, h=200):
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)    
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root.geometry("400x450")

Label = tk.Label(root, text = "Select Day", font = ("Helvetica", 15))
Label.pack(pady=50, padx=40)

helv15 = tkFont.Font(family = "Helvetica", size = 15)
root.lift()
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set("Today")
tk.Label(root, textvariable = v).pack()

def close_window(): 
    root.destroy()

today = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Today", variable = v, value = "Today", font = helv15).pack()
tomorrow = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Tomorrow", variable = v, value = "Tomorrow", font = helv15).pack()
submit = tk.Button(root, text = "Submit", command = close_window, font = helv15).pack()

center_window(400, 400) 

root.mainloop()

###THERE IS A CODE AFTER THIS POINT
```

[image]

The button that I want to add is "Cancel" button that stops the execution of the whole code and not just the loop of the Tkinter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just call exit

```
cancel = tk.Button(root, text = "Cancel", command = exit, font = helv15)
cancel.pack()
```

The pack method doesn't return anything, so you'll need to split the lines like this if you want to store the widgets

Comment: thanks for your comment...does it mean that I should also define `exit` function, so the `command` identifies itself correctly?

Comment: No problem! No, `exit()` is a built-in function that's already defined